# Vmwrite error when updating vmcs from kvm_vm_ioctl

Tags: c, linux-kernel, virtualization, kvm

i'm implementing an application on top of KVM in which I need to trap writes to CR3.

When I do this when handling a VM EXIT using: `vmcs_set_bits(CPU_BASED_VM_EXEC_CONTROL, CPU_BASED_CR3_LOAD_EXITING)`, it works correctly and I can see the traps in my log file.

Now when I do the same thing after receiving a command from Qemu (command is handled in `kvm_vm_ioctl` by calling a function I added to `kvm_x86_ops vmx_x86_ops`) I get a vmwrite error.

Here after the error log:

```
[  290.559474] start_vmi
[  290.559477] vmi: vmx.c: vmx_vmi_start_cr3_store_trapping: vmcs_read32(CPU_BASED_VM_EXEC_CONTROL) & CPU_BASED_CR3_LOAD_EXITING = 0
[  290.559480] vmwrite error: reg 4002 value c002 (err 16386)
[  290.559485] CPU: 0 PID: 3376 Comm: qemu-system-i38 Tainted: GF          O 3.13.0-32-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu

[  290.559513] Call Trace:
[  290.559525]  [<c1680147>] dump_stack+0x41/0x52
[  290.559533]  [<f89f289a>] vmwrite_error+0x35/0x3b [kvm_intel]
[  290.559538]  [<f89e6b95>] vmcs_writel+0x25/0x30 [kvm_intel]
[  290.559542]  [<f89e6c27>] vmcs_set_bits+0x27/0x40 [kvm_intel]
[  290.559547]  [<f89e6c83>] vmx_vmi_start_cr3_store_trapping+0x43/0x50 [kvm_intel]
[  290.559564]  [<fbf861a5>] kvm_vm_ioctl+0x3b5/0x740 [kvm]
[  290.559570]  [<c1150747>] ? __handle_mm_fault+0x127/0x280
[  290.559574]  [<c115093a>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x9a/0x150
[  290.559580]  [<c168ec77>] ? __do_page_fault+0x287/0x520
[  290.559593]  [<fbf85df0>] ? kvm_vm_release+0x20/0x20 [kvm]
[  290.559600]  [<c1194ae2>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x72/0x2e0
[  290.559604]  [<c1194de7>] SyS_ioctl+0x97/0xa0
[  290.559609]  [<c1692b4d>] sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
[  290.559614]  [<c1680000>] ? cfq_arm_slice_timer+0x14e/0x254
```

Does anyone has an idea why what's the problem ? I would be very grateful if there is any answer